# countForFetchRequest in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, core-data, swift2, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to use the `countForFetchRequest` method on a managed object context in Swift 2.0.

I note that the error handling for `executeFetchRequest` has been changed across to the new `do-try-catch` syntax:

```
func executeFetchRequest(_ request: NSFetchRequest) throws -> [AnyObject]
```

but the `countForFetchRequest` method still uses the legacy error pointer:

```
func countForFetchRequest(_ request: NSFetchRequest,
                    error error: NSErrorPointer) -> Int
```

...and I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to use this in Swift 2.0.

If I do the same thing as pre-Swift 2.0:

```
let error: NSError? = nil
let count = managedObjectContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
```

I get errors saying to remove the `&`, but if I remove that I get another error saying that `NSError` cannot be converted to an `NSErrorPointer`.

Any help would be appreciated about how to get this working.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but `error` needs to be a *variable*, in order to be passed as
inout-argument with `&`:

```
var error: NSError? = nil
let count = managedObjectContext.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
```

**Update:** As of **Swift 3,** `countForFetchRequest`
throws an error:

```
do {
    let count = try managedObjectContext.context.count(for:fetchRequest)
    return count
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Makes perfect sense. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

```
let error = NSErrorPointer()
let fetchResults = coreDataStack.context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: error)
print("Count \(fetchResults)")
```

This is the code for Swift 2.0