# Swift 2.3 NSFetchRequest

Tags: swift, core-data, migration, nsfetchrequest

Since migrating from 2.2 to 2.3 I now get an the following error:

> "Extra Argument in call" in the following code:

```
class func objectCountForEntity (entityName:String, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Int {

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
var error:NSError?
let count = context.countForFetchRequest(request, error: &error)

if let _error = error {
  print("\(#function) Error: \(_error.localizedDescription)")
} else {
  print("There are \(count) \(entityName) object(s) in \(context)")
}
return count
}
```

Could any one advise how I obtain an entity count in swift 2.3 since countForFetchRequest no longer functions in the way it did in swift 2.2

Comment: Actually for `countForFetchRequest`, it changed between 2.2 and 2.3. I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34652618/countforfetchrequest-in-swift-2-0 accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.1**

This is work for me.

```
class func objectCountForEntity (entityName:String, context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> Int {

let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
var error:NSError?
let count = try! context.count(for: request)

if let _error = error {
    print("\(#function) Error: \(_error.localizedDescription)")
} else {
    print("There are \(count) \(entityName) object(s) in \(context)")
}
return count
}
```